# Import multiple attributes with variations to woocommerce variable products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working with a script to import multiple attributes to a variable products.
I am getting attributes in the following format.

[image]

the code script is as follow

```
    function products_options_values($a) {
    $result = array(array());
    foreach ($a as $k => $list) {
        $_tmp = array();
        foreach ($result as $result_item) {
            foreach ($list as $list_item) {
                $_tmp[] = array_merge($result_item, array($k => $list_item));
            }
        }
        $result = $_tmp;
    }
    return $result;
}   if($attributes = get_result("select * from products_attributes where products_id = X ")){

wp_set_object_terms($product_id, 'variable', 'product_type');
$attrib_array = array();
$attrib_combo = array();
$max_price = $product['products_price'];
$min_price = $product['products_price'];

foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    $slug = sanitize_title($attribute['products_options_name']);
    $attrib_array[$slug] = array(
        'name' => $attribute['products_options_name'],
        'value' => ltrim($attrib_array[$slug]['value'] . ' | ' . $attribute['products_options_values_name'], ' | '),
        'position' => 0,
        'is_visible' => 1,
        'is_variation' => 1,
        'is_taxonomy' => 0);
    if($attribute['price_prefix'] == '-')$attributeprefix = '-';
    else if($attribute['price_prefix'] == '+')$attributeprefix = '+';
    else $attributeprefix = '';
    $attrib_combo[$slug][] = array($attribute['products_options_values_name'], $attributeprefix . $attribute['options_values_price']);
}



$combos = products_options_values($attrib_combo);


foreach ($combos as $combo) {

       $variation_id = wp_insert_post(array(
            'post_title' => 'Product ' . $product_id . ' Variation',
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'product_variation',
            'post_author' => 1,
            'post_parent' => $product_id
        ));

    $opt_price = $product['products_price'] .$attributeprefix. $attribute['options_values_price'];
    $special_price = $special['specials_new_products_price'];

    foreach ($combo as $k => $v) {

        update_post_meta($variation_id, 'attribute_' . $k, $v[0]);
        $opt_price += $v[1];
        $special_price += $v[1];
    }
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', $opt_price);
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_price', $opt_price);
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_thumbnail_id', 0);
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_stock', $product['products_quantity']);

    if ($opt_price > $max_price) {
        $max_price = $opt_price;
    }
    if ($opt_price < $min_price) {
        $min_price = $opt_price;
    }
}
update_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes', $attrib_array);
update_post_meta($product_id, '_max_variation_regular_price', $max_price);
update_post_meta($product_id, '_min_variation_regular_price', $min_price);
update_post_meta($product_id, '_max_variation_price', $max_price);
update_post_meta($product_id, '_min_variation_price', $min_price);}
```

with this code i can create attributes and variations successfully
but when i see in the website and select a variable product and click add to cart button error display

> Invalid value posted for

I am not understanding where I have error or missing some meta field to cover.

help me seniors if i am missing some meta fields or somethin code issues.

Comment: Did you rename `htaccess.txt` file to `.htaccess`? Check instructions in popup for option *Use URL Rewriting*

Comment: is there anyone who can sort out the problem please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for giggles and kicks - in your config file - is your live site set to your home URL, or is it blank? you should make sure it will be empty. I have had some really weird things happen with SEF when that is not configured properly.

You also have a lot of script going on - especially on that front page. If the site is working without the SEF installed, and broken when it is turned on - more than likely a confict.

Just a side note - Joomla's core SEF works just fine. Don't bother with third party stuff - you really do not need it.