# All Links Display Home Page on Home page in joomla

Tags: joomla

I just finished my website design, but encountered a problem, all the links in my main page, redirect to the home page! but other pages are working fine, any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Maybe you can ask your question there : http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [I need some help on joomla, all links redirect to homepage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667178/i-need-some-help-on-joomla-all-links-redirect-to-homepage)

Comment: can we see some code?

Comment: Are you sure they are redirecting to the homepage and not just displaying the homepage modules on all the links?

Comment: it's redirecting, because the address changes, but I only see the homepage @itoctopus